# Can we create an IntentService as STICKY?

Tags: android, intentservice, android-intentservice

The document says intentservice calls stopself implicitly. So was wondering if intentservice can be made  Sticky.

Thanks

Comment: yes it can be sticky,  but still the service will call stopSelf()

Comment: So will it be like stopping itself and then again restarting all the time?

Comment: no,  if you call stopSelf its stopped until you startService again

Comment: I dont have to call StopSelf() It calls stopSelf() on its own, that's why it is an intentservice, my question is when it calls stopself() ON ITS OWN will it again restart or remain stopped?

Comment: no, if stopSelf is called its stopped until you startService again

Answer (score 0):

sticky is like a property (it´s not a property) that you can give to a service, and it gets activated after the system shuts it down because of low memory, when the system has enough memory it will restart the services that return START_STICKY on their onStartCommand, otherwise the will remain off. In IntentServices you cannot return START_STICKY (at least i haven't found the way) but what you can do is:

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }
```

currently i´m using it in my app and it works well